# How do I find an expression for $f(n)$ in terms of $n$ (supposing I assume $n$ is a power of 2)?

Tags: recursion, recursive-algorithms

If an algorithm runs in time $f(n)$, according to the recursion: $$f(n) = nf(n/2).$$where $f(1)=1$. How do I find an expression for $f(n)$ in terms of $n$ (supposing I assume $n$ is a power of 2) ?

My solution:
Given, $f(n) = nf\left( \frac{n}{2}\right) = 1$.\
Suppose $\mathbf{n}$ is a power of 2 i.e $n=2^k$ for some positive integer k.\
Therefore,
\begin{align}
    f(n) &= nf\left( \frac{n}{2}\right) \nonumber \\
    &= n\cdot \frac{n}{2} \cdot f\left(\frac{n}{2^2}\right) \nonumber \\
    &= n\cdot \frac{n}{2} \cdot \frac{n}{2^2} \cdot f\left( \frac{n}{2^3}\right) \nonumber \\
    \Rightarrow{} f(n) &= n\cdot \frac{n}{2} \cdot \frac{n}{2^2} \cdot\cdot\cdot \frac{n}{2^{k-1}} \cdot f\left( \frac{n}{2^k}\right) \nonumber \\
    \Rightarrow{} f(n) &= n\cdot \frac{n}{2} \cdot \frac{n}{2^2} \cdot\cdot\cdot \frac{n}{2^{k-1}} \cdot f\left( \frac{2^k}{2^k}\right) \quad \mathbf{since  \quad n = 2^k} \nonumber \\
    \Rightarrow{} f(n) &= n\cdot \frac{n}{2} \cdot \frac{n}{2^2} \cdot\cdot\cdot \frac{n}{2^{k-1}} \cdot f(1) \nonumber \\
     &= n \nonumber \\
     \Rightarrow{} f(n) &= n\cdot \frac{n}{2} \cdot \frac{n}{2^2} \cdot\cdot\cdot \frac{n}{2^{k-1}} \cdot 1 \nonumber \\
      \Rightarrow{} f(n) &= \frac{n^k}{2\cdot 2^2 \cdot 2^3 \cdot\cdot\cdot 2^{k-1}} \nonumber \\
      &= \frac{n^k}{2^{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}} \nonumber 
\end{align}
Thus, the expression for $f(n)$ in terms of $n$ is:
$$f(n) = \frac{n^k}{2^{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}}$$

How can I simplify my final expression further so that it does not include k?

Comment: Haven't read the whole proof but if $n=2^k$ then $k=\log_2 n$, no?

Comment: Does this suffice? \begin{align}
        \Rightarrow f(n) &= \frac{n^k}{2^{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}} = \frac{n^{\log_2 n}}{2^{\frac{\log_2 n(\log_2 n-1)}{2}}} \nonumber \\
         &= \frac{n^{\log_2 n}}{2^{\frac{\log_2 n(\log_2 n-1)}{\log_2 4}}} \nonumber \\
         &= \frac{n^{\log_2 n}}{n^{{\frac{1}{2}}(\log_2n-1)}} \nonumber \\
         &= n^{\log_2 n - \frac{1}{2}(\log_2n-1)} \nonumber \\
         \therefore f(n) &= n^{\frac{1}{2}(\log_2 n + 1)} \nonumber
    \end{align}